# MVC 5 Razor - Display text instead id

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, razor, model-view-controller

I'm building a project management system and project table keep the project type id - and the value of the project type stored in another table (ProjectTypes).
I'm sending all of the projects by json, and I can't pull the type name, only ID...
How should I handle it ?

Project Class:

```
public class Project
{
    //Connection with DB Layer
    DataLayer dal = new DataLayer();
    private const string CClassName = "Project";

    /*All Properties of Project object*/

    #region Properties

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string NameHeb { get; set; }
    public string NameEng { get; set; }
    public int type_id { get; set; }
    public int Category { get; set; }
    public int lecturer1 { get; set; }
    public int lecturer2 { get; set; }
    public string shortDescription { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string NeededKnowledge { get; set; }
    public int StageID { get; set; }
    public int thumbnailID { get; set; }
    public byte isActive { get; set; }
    public byte isApproved { get; set; }
    public byte isAttached { get; set; }
}
```

Project Type:

```
public class ProjectType
{
    //Connection with DB
    DataLayer dal = new DataLayer();

    #region Properties
    /* Straight object properties */
    public int DepID { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
    public byte isActive { get; set; }
    #endregion
}
```

Controller:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public JsonResult ProjectsByJSON()
{
    List<Project> objProjects = new Project().GetAllProjects();
    return Json(objProjects, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

View:

```
<div id="login">
    <div class="Table" id="ProjectsTbl">

        <div class="Heading">
            <div class="Cell">
            </div>
            <div class="Cell">
                <p>Project name</p>
            </div>
            <div class="Cell">
                <p>Type</p>
            </div>
            <div class="Cell">
                <p>Description</p>
            </div>
            <div class="Cell">
                <p>stage</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script language="javascript">
            $.get("ProjectsByJSON", null, BindData);

            function BindData(curProjects)
            {
                var tbl = $("#ProjectsTbl");

                for (i=0; i<curProjects.length;i++)
                {
                    var row = "<div class=\"Row\">" +
                            "<div class=\"Cell\"></div>" +
                            "<div class=\"Cell\">" + curProjects[i].NameHeb + "</div>" +
                            "<div class=\"Cell\">" + curProjects[i].Name + "</div>" +
                            "<div class=\"Cell\">" + curProjects[i].shortDescription + "</div>" +
                            "<div class=\"Cell\">" + curProjects[i].Stage + "</div>" +
                         "</div>";
                    tbl.append(row);
                }
            }
        </script>

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think the best way is to code by join both tables (Project and ProjectTypes) and return the same. Then you will get both Id and Name.

Comment: Thanks for practical solution